# Passing type argument to a generic custom class

Tags: vb.net, class, generics

I've seen a lot of chatter on this topic. Though the examples and desired outcomes are always very specific and specialized. Any direction on this is appreciated.

Custom Class:

```
Public Class customClass(Of T, S)
[include properties]
[include methods]
End Class
```

Implementation of Class:

```
dim [string] as string = string.empty
dim [type] as type = [string].gettype 

dim instance as customClass(of [type], integer)
```

Also note, I've read that vb.net does not allow you to pass parameters to its constructor. I refuse to accept that you can't pass a type to a class and generate objects dependent on the type of that argument. Is the only answer to this a function in the class which returns a list of objects cast to the desired type? Your time is appreciated.

This question is motivated by academic research. The above is "what I am trying to do" thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kind of hard to see what you're trying to do, but if I'm reading this right, you're trying to take a variable and use that as the generic argument. This is not possible in .NET - when you declare a variable of a generic class, you need a compile-time type as the generic argument, so it cannot be the a variable of type Type.

This is important for a couple of reasons, one of which is to ensure that type constraints are met.

So:

```
Class Foo(Of T)
End Class

Dim x as Type = GetType(String)
Dim y as Foo(Of x)
```

does not work - you have to do:

```
Dim y as Foo(Of String)
```

There's always reflection and expression trees, but that's more of a hack than a solution.

Comment: what language can i implement my original intention in?

Comment: I doubt there's a type-safe way of doing this in any language, since it would require the compiler to know things about the runtime prior to compilation. You can do it in .NET, but it will be entirely type-unsafe, with a lot of casts to/from `object`, and using reflection to instantiate objects, and probably a bunch of other ugliness. If you're going in that direction, you can probably do it in any language, by taking away the type-safety of it, or just using a dynamic language from the beginning (like Ruby or javascript).

Comment: If there's a business need behind this, not just academic, I'd suggest taking a step back and trying to solve your problem from a different angle, since there's probably a better answer.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't put much thought into the actual overflow potential to something so dynamic. Thanks for the contribution.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use dynamic types to call this kind of typed declarations `(Of t,s)` but you can 'group' or delimit several types using interfaces or inheritance, which could also be very useful.

```
Class customClass(Of T As iMyInterface, s As iMyInterface)
End Class

Interface iMyInterface
End Interface

Class MyClass1
    Implements iMyInterface
End Class
Class MyClass2
    Implements iMyInterface
End Class

Dim y As New customClass(Of MyClass1, MyClass2)
```